# How to serialize JSON with Object containing both primitives and List<> types?

Tags: json, serialization, gson

So I have a class that I was planning on using for simple JSON serialization.

```
public class Thing {

  private int field1;
  private String some_other_field;
  private List<SubType> subs;
  private list<AnotherType> another;

  public String toJson() {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    g.toJson(this);
  }
}
```

So the documentation shows that if you want to serialize generic types, you need to specify a TypeToken:

```
Type listtype = new TypeToken<List<SubType>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(subs, listtype);
```

But then, how does this work if I have a whole class I want to serialize for?  Where do I get to specify the serialization type for those two `List<>` types so that I can just pass the whole object in and get a serialized output?  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc it seems that if you serialize a complete object with toJson(...), it deals with the generics attributes properly.

[toJson(Object)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html)

"Note that this method works fine if the any of the object fields are of generic type, just the object itself should not be of a generic type"

What output did you get with your object ?

Comment: It was throwing exceptions, but apparently I was doing something wrong with it.  It seems to work dandy...now I'm curious why I was having problems in the first place...